# Best resources to learn about graphics and imaging?

Tags: graphics, imaging, color-space

Having spent a bunch of time recently doing 2D work that involves pixel manipulation of bitmaps and blending/compositing, I've run up against the limits of my own understanding with respect to colorspaces, non-RGB color worlds, etc.

I'd like to go back to basics and learn how all this stuff actually works, so that I'm not shooting in the dark next time I need to think about how to set up a blend function, and I know how to play with color palettes, etc.

Any pointers for good places to start on the path? Online references good, actual books that are clearly written are better. (Not looking for something that's just piles of equations, but can follow mathy stuff if it's not too terse.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked these tutorials:

http://www.student.kuleuven.be/~m0216922/CG/index.html